# Running multiple web services on one website

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have a web service that I need to run on a website. It is likely that I will need to add other web services in the future.

Can you run multiple services on a website? Or is it better to run just one service per website?

If I do it the first way, does it interupt other services already on the site every time I need to add a new one? What is the best approach when running multiple web services? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using REST, SOAP, or something else to provide the web service?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I am using a WCF service.

Comment: You can create multiple Web services to expose various slices of data in your system to other applications and to facilitate loosely coupled integrations and service oriented architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the web services on iis7. There is a new concept of having different applications within a website in IIS7. This will resolve your problem if you are running the website on IIS7.

To answer you correctly, I need more inputs.

Creating different website for different web service is anyways very much beneficial since if one website is down consumer of second webservice can still access the second webserice.

If both the webservices are catering only one business and very much inter dependent you should create only one website and have all related webservices there.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Each "project", weather it is a website, a web service, or something else is run in its own instance.
You can have a virtual directory inside a website (eg, http://example.com/virtualDirectory)

In IIS 6 and 7, you can setup something called "Application Pools"
This lets your website, web service, or something else, run on that Application Pool. 
Each application pool has its own thread. If an application pool crashes, the only websites that will be affected are the ones using that application pool.
It is a good idea to have a separate application pool for each website/service.

Here is an articles
http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/working-application-pools-internet-information-server.html

And a youtube video:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i6GlDKGMdZA

Good luck!

Comment: Note that Application Pools run within a separate worker process (not a separate thread).